# Xamarin 4.3.0.784 is missing the connected device dropdown box

Tags: xamarin, deployment, xamarin.android

After updating Xamarin Android from version 4.1.2.18 to the latest version 4.3.0.784 the android device dropdown selection box has disappear, it is not present. I also attached it to a phone but I get a fail to deploy error...and it states please select a device. But there's no selection dropdown box. Also, Xamarin Studio is deploying and working OK.

I'm running VS 2015 Community on Windows 10. The Android toolbox menu option was selected, and it only shows some tool icons... and not dropdown box.

Answer (score 0):

A Microsoft and Xamarin engineer are investigating the issue. It appears to be a bug in the software which is system depended.

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI. I am having the same issue with VS 2015, but it is working in VS 2017